# Can a Wizard write spells in something other than a spellbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, equipment, spellcasting

So basically I have a bard that I am about to multiclass into a wizard. I’d like to know if it’s possible to not need a grimoire specifically, but be able to say write my spells by writing them on or carving them into my characters lute?
Obviously the space on the instrument used to write spells on and challenges of carving the spells would be limiting/possibly difficult, which is a whole other bag of issues I’m not worrying about just yet.

I just want to know if this is at all possible. I’ve read the PHB and it doesn’t seem to say anywhere that you must use a spell book to write your spells in, nor that there’s much difference from writing in a spell book vs say, a piece of wood you carry with you.

However, I could have possibly missed somewhere where it says you cannot. Either way any help or insight given is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by carving spells on the lute? Is this a matter of story/worldbuilding, or do you want to deliberately combine several different game mechanics into a single thing? (musical instrument, spellcasting focus, spellbook, what else... a weapon maybe?)

Comment: Wouldn't be a duplicate if it was specifically about instruments.

Comment: While the usual caveat of "work with your DM" goes for stuff like this, the question was already answered, in terms of "no, it does not have to be a book."  While that may be contingent on your DM's liking or not liking what's in Xanathar's Guide, what you propose fits into that Q&A.